# Axios GET returns non-readable response

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have an express app with a simple GET with axios (1.2.0):

```
const result: AxiosResponse = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
```

The result.data ends up a cryptic, badly encoded string:

```
k�H���>������T��N.���r�H�v �_"9'?1���J��\���LA.  ��H���!�b�R� 9�܅��ڹ�K�}��%��A�v�Q*�g�dwf� ..goes long
```

I have tried with different configs added to the request but no luck.
Also couldn't find any related posts elsewhere.

Why would this be? How could I fix it?

Comment: Hmmm, I cannot reproduce your error with your identical code.  What version of nodejs are you running?  That type of gibberish sometimes means gzip compression was used, but not properly decompressed.

Comment: Are you seeing this output on your server (where you made the axios call)?  Or are you sending this response from your server to your client and seeing this gibberish in the client?

Comment: I tried it on a repl session and I'm getting the same decoding error for the json. Gzip compression is being used by the server. It has an ```'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br' ``` header.

Comment: This is a known issue in the latest axios version https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298  Easiest workaround: Downgrade to axios@1.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### In v1.2.1 fixed this error.

You need to add `Accept-Encoding` with application/json in axios.get header.

The default of it is `gzip`

You can use 1.2 with this code

```
const axios = require('axios')

const getTitles = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get(
            'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json',
                }
            }
        );
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.data, null, 4));
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
    }
};

getTitles();
```

Result

```
$ node titles.js
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio r
eprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et
cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem
eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor b
eatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut
 reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
    },
    removed
```

Comment: Be aware, that with removing `gzip` from the `Accept-Encoding` header, you are also losing the benefits of HTTP compression for those requests. Might not be a problem for small responses though ... Might be better to downgrade to axios@1.1 and wait for the known issue to be fixed, which will probably happen pretty soon ...

Comment: Been trying to figure this out for quite some time! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Tried GET using chrome dev console and the request works. Data gets decoded correctly.

```
resp = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(res=> res.json())
```

So I guess this is an axios problem. Try using older versions.

---

This seems like a problem with the JsonPlaceholder API.

Axios can't decode the Json correctly probably because of some server misconfiguration regarding compression.

I tried GET with another url having the same response headers and the same compression and it worked fine.

```
axios.default.get("https://reddit.com/r/android.json")
```

Comment: This is an issue with the latest 1.2 version of axios https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298 As a workaround downgrade to axios@1.1