# Axios returns odd string when used on remote backend

Tags: node.js, next.js, axios, fetch-api, strapi

Currently i am working on a project with a Headless CMS using Strapi and for the frontend/backend i am using NEXT.js. The CMS should return valid JSON data.

Next.Js is using REST Calls, to fetch the data from Strapi.
I use axios in the getStaticProp method from NEXT.js and everything works fine.

Since i had something working i moved on deploying it on a real Server, but since i deployed Strapi to a real server, my NEXT.js Application is getting very weird encoded Data. I would blame it on a Server , but with fetch() in NEXT.js, POSTMAN and also in the Browser i get a correct JSON.
This leads me to think that i miss some configuration in Axios.

But i am really not sure what is going on, if it's a server side problem or a Axios Problem.

So here some Code :

```
var res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/posts")
var data = res.data
```

This is working fine and returns a valid json. But when using the Backend URL it is still working with fetch, but not with Axios anymore.

```
var res = await fetch("http://server.url/api/posts")
var data = res.json()
```

This is working fine and i get valid JSON data on the remote server and returns a valid json. Also using POSTMAN and trying the URL in the Browser works fine.

But if i use Axios, it looks like some encoding problems

```
var res = await axios.get("http://server.url/api/posts")
var data = res.data
```

Now data contains some wrong coded string --> "▼♥��Kn�0►��↕�[�%�O�.Ȧ@�t◄�ZtA�DJđ
�j�→�IoӋu(
�♥��‼�����∟Ή�C
��X�3�+▬rnҶ˱exb��92d�&�*U�l��R�D��▼�Kl�Đ��&��k  ��l�F)P{���J�vG:�L���HJe���Ȏ����▼�c>����E���ǆ����↓_����∟��k�]     �rK��ү7��4��♠�"����☺j�~�g�↕C��^O�z��>�*���Ǻ]�vh$7z�u    \�e�5j↕��zFn9q�↓�����7�a[w�".��QX�[4↔,�s�↨M�|�;↑��0��↓���3^=��&���@���.��B���<,V`∟נ�l��s>ͥSE8V`�
�L♣�jz�/mC�s��  ▬☺�8�\x�
��¯↨�-*ť↔∟↑�E�_��X�͉↔�c�BNu5�h����p|H�i☺�Veu[w§�§��u������♥���k�♦"
I also tried using responseType : json in the request.

Thanks alot in advance :)

Comment: it was hot issue on axios [v1.2.0 defect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74566024/axios-get-returns-non-readable-response/74567911#74567911).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
responseType: 'arraybuffer'
```

Or:

```
responseType: 'stream'
```